# How HTTP client detect web server crash

Tags: http, tcp

From [HTTP:The definitive guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925090.do) :

> But without Content-Length, clients cannot distinguish between
>   successful connection close at the end of a message and connection
>   close due to a server crash in the middle of a message.

Let's assume that for this purpose the "server crash" means crash of the server's HW or OS without closing the TCP connection or possibly link being broken.

If the web server crashes without closing TCP connection, how does the client detect that the connection "has been closed"?

From what I know, if FIN segment is not sent the client will keep waiting for the data unless there is a timer or it tries to send some  data (failing which detects TCP connection shutdown).

How is this done in HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

> If the web server crashes without closing TCP connection, how does the client detect that the connection "has been closed"?

Since the closing will be done by the kernel that would mean, that the whole system crashed or that the connection broke somewhere else (router crashed, power blackout at server side or similar).

You can only detect this if you sent data to the server and don't get any useful response back.

> From what I know, if FIN segment is not sent the client will keep waiting for the data unless there is a timer or it tries to send some data (failing which detects TCP connection shutdown).
>
> How is this done in HTTP?

HTTP uses TCP as the underlying protocol, so if TCP detects a connection close HTTP will too. Additionally HTTP can detect in most cases if the response is complete, by using information from Content-length header or similar information with chunked transfer encoding. In the few cases where the end of response is only indicated by a connection close HTTP can only rely on TCP do detect problems. So far the theory, but in practice most browsers simply ignore an incomplete response and show as much as they got.